# Fixing Chimney leak and ceiling damage

Tags: repair, ceiling, leak, waterproofing, chimney

I got a quote from contractor to fix chimney leaking water during rain to ceiling. There is drywall damage to ceiling too as result.

What he is recommending is ripping off the roof 2 feet around the chimney and redo that to fix the leak. He thinks the leak has likely to do with flashing but just working with flashing from outside may not be enough or may not last.

So I am not sure if ripping of 2 feet around the chimney is the best way. My roof is around 5 years old. His estimate it about $3500.

What should I do? I feel like just leaking proofing the flashing might be enough?

He didn't climb up the roof, the observation were from ground. Thanks. This is in US, east coast.

**Update**

I went through the estimate closely and a lot if is going towards repair of the ceilings which is spread over two rooms. Due to dry-wall patching  in each room (multiple sq ft), he says the whole ceiling will need repainting to look same. The chimney leak part itself is $1300.

The estimate also includes ripping off the crown molding and reattaching.

Comment: threre's indoor work to the ceiling finish, too, but that may come in an can and apply with a bush.

Comment: Knowing only what I know from your post, I tend to agree with your contractor. He's setting himself up for a dissatisfied customer if he puts a band-aid on the flashing without having a good understanding of what's leaking. Also, there's no good way to fix bad flashing. You have to redo it. This may mean applying self-adhesive membrane to key areas as well.

Comment: Do you have the contractor information that did the roof 5 years ago?  If so, many reputable roofers warranty their work, so check to see if it's covered that way.

Comment: @Randall Good point but it was done by previous owner, don't have any info on him.

Comment: I too have a similar problem, but there is no significant damage visible on the drywall. The problem is, it sounds like your contractor gave you a rough wag, and it sounds like the contractor was NOT a mason. Without LOOKING and identifying sources of water, he didnt do you justice. You may have a crown issue (I do). Broken bricks, broken mortar, etc. If those are issues, his cost is going up, your cost is going up, and the drywall will be damaged again. Get it fixed, confirm it is fixed, then address drywall. I doubt (strong opinion), that "waterproofing" the flashing will do anything for you

Comment: Call 3-5 more contractors, try to ensure you are calling a reputable contractor. Ask questions, have them explain what they are going to do. Tell them you are getting additional estimates, and ask them to sell to you what they are going to do, and why they are better IN WRITING. Also calling the roofer as @randall suggested is a super great idea, (it also gives him a chance to say "it isnt the flashing.... which could be true).